# Doctrine Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class XXX does not exist'

Tags: php, mysql, orm, doctrine

I'm trying to insert in a mysql database. I'm using doctrine and standar PHP (no frameworks). I have 3 tables with their 3 PHP classes

```
<?php

namespace model\dto;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Canales
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="Canales")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Canales
{

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Nombre", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $nombre;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="URL", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $url;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="imagen", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $imagen;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Ingles", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $ingles;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="Id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

...
}

<?php

namespace model\dto;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Playlist
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="playlist", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idCanal", columns={"idCanal"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Playlist
{

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="idYoutube", type="string", length=34, nullable=false)
 */
private $idYoutube;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="descripcion", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $descripcion;

/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ingles", type="boolean", nullable=false)
 */
private $ingles;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="titulo", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $titulo;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="imagen", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $imagen;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \Canales
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Canales")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idCanal", referencedColumnName="Id")
 * })
 */
private $idcanal;
...
}

<?php

namespace model\dto;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Videos
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="videos", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="idPlaylist", columns={"idPlaylist"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Videos
{

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="idYoutube", type="string", length=34, nullable=false)
 */
private $idYoutube;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="titulo", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $titulo;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="imagen", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $imagen;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var \Playlist
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Playlist")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="idPlaylist", referencedColumnName="idPlaylist")
 * })
 */
private $idplaylist;

...
}
```

Also, I have this dao for insert and query

```
<?php

abstract class daoGenerico{

private $entityManager;

/**
 * Class Constructor
 * @param    $entityManager   
 */
public function __construct()
{
    require("bootstrap.php");

    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}


/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEntityManager()
{
    return $this->entityManager;
}

function listAll($nombre){
    $repositorio = 'model\dto\\'.$nombre;
    $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository($repositorio);

    $entityList = $repository->findAll();

    if (!$entityList) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No product found'
        );
    }
    return $entityList;
}

function findByIdYoutube($nombre, $entity){
    $existe = true;
    $repositorio = 'model\dto\\'.$nombre;
    $repository = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository($repositorio);

    $entity = $repository->findOneBy(array('idYoutube' => $entity->getIdYoutube()));

    return $entity;
}   

function insert($entity){
    $entityM= $this->getEntityManager();

    $entityM->merge($entity);
    $entityM->flush();
}

}
?>
```

My test.php is this

```
<?php
function getPlaylists($idCanal) {

    $key = 'XXXX';
    $channel = $idCanal; //ejemplo: UCL-aihy3UD61TmvCOL9szUw

    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlists?key=$key&channelId=$channel&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50";

    $json = file_get_contents($url);

    $obj = json_decode($json, true);

    //var_dump($obj);

    return $obj;
}

function getVideosByPlaylists($idPlaylist) {

    $key = 'XXXXX';

    $url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?key=$key&playlistId=$idPlaylist&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=50";

    $json = file_get_contents($url);

    $obj = json_decode($json, true);

    //var_dump($obj);

    return $obj;
}

include_once('./src/model/dao/daoGenerico.php');
include_once('./src/model/dao/daoCanal.php');
include_once('./src/model/dao/daoPlaylist.php');
include_once('./src/model/dao/daoVideo.php');
include_once('./src/model/dto/Playlist.php');
include_once('./src/model/dto/Videos.php');

$daoCanal = new daoCanal();
$daoPlaylist = new daoPlaylist();
$daoVideo = new daoVideo();
$canales = $daoCanal->listAll('Canales');

foreach ($canales as $canal) {
    echo ($canal->getNombre()."\n");

    //buscamos las playlist del canal
    $playlistsYT = getPlaylists($canal->getUrl());

    foreach ($playlistsYT['items'] as $playlistYT) {

        //obtenemos los valores y buscamos en BD si ya existe esa playlist
        $idcanal = $canal;
        $idYoutube = $playlistYT["id"];
        $titulo = $playlistYT["snippet"]["title"];
        $descripcion = $playlistYT["snippet"]["description"];
        $imagen = $playlistYT["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["high"]["url"];
        $ingles = $canal->getIngles();

        $playlist = new model\dto\Playlist($idYoutube, $descripcion, $ingles, $titulo, $imagen, $idcanal);

        $playlistBD = $daoPlaylist->findByIdYoutube('Playlist',$playlist);

        if(!$playlistBD){
            //si no existe, se crea
            echo ("-->".$playlist->getTitulo()."\n");
            $daoPlaylist->insert($playlist);
            $playlistBD = $daoPlaylist->findByIdYoutube('Playlist',$playlist);
        }
        //actualizamos el objeto $playlist para guardar el id generado
        $playlist->setId($playlistBD->getId());

        //buscamos los videos correspondientes a esa playlist
        $videosYT = getVideosByPlaylists($playlist->getidYoutube());

        foreach ($videosYT['items'] as $videoYT) {

            //obtenemos los valores
            $idPlaylist = $playlist;
            $idYoutube = $videoYT["snippet"]["resourceId"]["videoId"];
            $titulo = $videoYT["snippet"]["title"];

            //si el video no tiene thumbnails, es que ha sido eliminado o es privado
            if(isset($videoYT["snippet"]["thumbnails"])){
                $imagen = $videoYT["snippet"]["thumbnails"]["high"]["url"];

                $video = new model\dto\Videos($idYoutube, $titulo, $imagen, $idPlaylist);

                //buscamos en BD si ya existe ese video
                $existe = $daoVideo->findByIdYoutube('Videos',$video);
                var_dump($video);
                if(!$existe){
                    echo ("-->".$video->getTitulo()."\n");
                    $daoVideo->insert($video);
                }   
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

My problem ocurrs when this line is executed

> $daoVideo->insert($video);

I can insert and query in playlist step and query in video step but no insert video. This is the error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class Canales does not exist' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yoga/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php:960
Stack trace:
#0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yoga/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php(960): ReflectionParameter->getClass()
#1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yoga/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php(908): Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyGenerator->getParameterType(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata), Object(ReflectionMethod), Object(ReflectionParameter))
#2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yoga/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/ProxyGenerator.php(780): Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyGenerator->buildParametersString(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata), Object(ReflectionMethod), Array)
#3 [internal function]: Doctrine\Common\Proxy\ProxyGenerator->generateMethods(Object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata))
#4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yoga/vendor/doctrine/c in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/yoga/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Proxy/Exception/UnexpectedValueException.php on line 57
```

Any idea or advice about this error?

thanks in advance

Comment: I have found the solution. In my class, setCanal was like this public function setIdcanal(Canales $idcanal = null). I had to change it for this: public function setIdcanal(\model\dto\Canales $idcanal = null)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. In my class, setCanal was like this

`public function setIdcanal(Canales $idcanal = null) {
...
}`

I had to change it for this:

```
public function setIdcanal(\model\dto\Canales $idcanal = null) { 
...
}
```